# Prevent users from changing LAN settings

Tags: windows-7, permissions, dns, administrator, opendns

I'd like to stop my kids from changing either the LAN or WAN settings on PC or Laptop.

I'm using OpenDNS and have it set to use their DNS servers, but my kids keep removing the DNS settings to access sites which I don't want them to access.

I'd like for them to otherwise have administrator settings, but not be able to change the network settings.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, a site for computer *programming* questions. Note that questions on computer *usage* are more appropriate for our sister site, http://SuperUser.com ; I have voted to migrate your question there. In the meantime: I suggest that you create a limited (non-administrator) account for them and have them use it - administrative privileges are required to change network settings. See e.g. this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee623984(WS.10).aspx

Comment: You are letting your kids have admin rights?!

Comment: @David Heffernan: Now, now. Windows 7 continues the proud tradition of "by default, everyone has admin rights", even though the UAC has mitigated this somewhat. Although this can be configured otherwise, a less-experienced user may not even be aware of the possibility of limiting user rights.

Answer (score 1):

First Try this:

By the way test this:
first remove your child account from Administrator

1-Right Click On Computer -->>Manage -->>Local User And groups\User

2-By default your Administrator User is disable and there is another user which you create during windows installation for example it's Jack

3-Right click on Jack and select Properties

4-In the Member of Tab remove the "Network Configuration Operators" from the user and click Apply and OK

5-Restart your Computer

Hope it is work for you
[Prohibit Access to LAN Connection Properties](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/prohibit-access-to-lan-connection-properties/)

check this on ServerFault [How to disable Tcp/Ip settings in windows 7 via GPO?](https://serverfault.com/questions/108800/how-to-disable-tcp-ip-settings-in-windows-7-via-gpo)

and this at microsoft technet 
[Configure network connection restrictions with Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732613%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Does this require Windows 7 Professional?