# Filtering some websites from internet router

Tags: windows-7, router, internet, website

I want to filter out some websites in my home. I have a few computers in my home all of which are connected to internet. I want to block some sites like `adult sites` for all the computers.

I don't want to block these sites using any software or something because eventually the protection will be gone when the software is uninstalled.

I want to block it from the dsl router through which all the computers are connected to internet.

My router name is `huawei EchoLife HG510a`.

Regards

Comment: You are approaching it the wrong way. You will never be able to block all adult sites yourself, that is a full time job. So leave that to the companies who make these lists and use their software, either a DNS solution or a internet filtering software package. Good filtering software cannot easily be disabled or uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a good product that blocks not only sites of a certain category but also bad sites(ie trojans and etc) is [**OpenDNS**](http://www.opendns.com/about/).  They do have a free Home version.  I have been using it at home to block kids from seeing inappropriate stuff and it works great.  [**Here is the link**](https://store.opendns.com/get/home-free?__utma=247635969.1716104614.1360334809.1360334809.1360334809.1&__utmb=247635969.4.10.1360334809&__utmc=247635969&__utmx=-&__utmz=247635969.1360334809.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=opendns&__utmv=-&__utmk=179156135) to register for the home version.  Just select the Home version and sign up.

Comment: Good solution, but you should add that he will have to [prevent the users from changing DNS settings again](http://superuser.com/questions/361053/prevent-users-from-changing-lan-settings).

Answer (score 0):

[EchoLife HG510 Home Gateway User Manual](http://www.basis-net.ru/images/img/device/huawei/smartax/pdf/hg510.pdf)

User Manual
EchoLife HG510 Home Gateway Chapter 3 Configuration Guide

Figure 3-30 Advanced Setup – Firewall – Outgoing IP Filtering
Setup

P 52.